# awk division without rounding

Tags: unix, awk

I'm working on a file that contains a series of decimal values with different precision.
I need to divide these numbers by 100 and I don't need to round.

```
awk '{val = $1 / 100; print val}' input_file.txt
```

**Input file:**

```
0.123456789012
0.123456789012345
0.12345678901234567
```

**output:**

```
0.00123457
0.00123457
0.00123457
```

**I would like not to round the result and get the following output:**

```
0.00123456789012
0.00123456789012345
0.0012345678901234567
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: awk numbers are not decimal, but binary floating point. You may get more precision with `awk -v OFMT=%.17g '...'`, but exactly the output you expect. If all numbers are of the form `0.XXXX` you can simply `sub(/\./, ".00", $1)` ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

interesting problem since you want different precision for different numbers.  Here is one workaround

```
$ awk '{d=length($1); printf "%."d"f\n", $1/100}' file

0.00123456789012
0.00123456789012345
0.0012345678901234567
```

this should cover numbers greater than 1 as well.

```
$ awk '{d=length($1); if($1>1) d+=1-length(int($1)); printf "%."d"f\n", $1/100}' file
```

may need to tweak for negative numbers...

Comment: You can use `printf "%.*f\n", d, $1/100` to provide the precision as a printf argument rather than concatenating it into the format string.

Comment: Use `sprinf` function, which will return a string.

Comment: it doesn't take that much to have `%f` start ruining numbers : `echo 0.0012345678901234567891234567 |  awk '{d=length($1);printf "%.*f\n", d, $1/100 }'` ::::::::  `0.000012345678901234567807461764`

Comment: while a small `PREC=128` for `gmp` would come up short for inputs like this : `echo 0.1234567890123456789123456789012345678901 | gawk -v PREC=128 -Mbe  '{d=length($1);printf "%.*f\n", d, $1/100 }'` ::::::::::: `0.001234567890123456789123456789012345678903`

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{sub(/\./,".00")} 1' Input_file
```

---

---

With OP's original command:

```
awk '{val = $1 / 100; sub(/\./,".00",val);print val}' input_file.txt
```